# DRY code using Rspec matchers

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to improve the following block of code to be more readable/concise/DRY (my actual arguments are a bit more complicated to `#have_css`):

```
negate ? expect(page).to(have_css('selector', text: 'text')): expect(page).to_not(have_css('selector', text: 'text'))
```

Is there anyway to store `'selector', text: 'text'` in a variable to be reused as method arguments?

Or alternatively is there some special trick I could do to only call the correct matcher based on my `negate` boolean value? Perhaps something similar to

```
expectation = negate ? :should_not : :should
page.send(expectation, have_css('selector', text: 'text'))`
```

but using the new Rspec expect syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the arguments to be used more than once in an array, then splat (`*`) them into the argument list:

```
css_args = ['selector', {text: 'text'}]
expect(page).to(have_css(*css_args))
```

You can also pick your matcher with `negate` like so:

```
expectation = negate ? :to_not : :to
expect(page).send(expectation, have_css('selector', text: 'text'))
```

Comment: There's a huge variation, I'm happy to help :)